# How can I fix flexbox contents taking a seperate line for each space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to flexbox and CSS. I'm trying to design this navbar where the flexbox contents taking an unnecessary linebreak for a single word. Please tell me how to fix that issue.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo-title #logo {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 20%;
  margin: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  /* left: 40%; */
}


/* =================================================================
   Layout
   ================================================================= */

header {
  background: #869189;
  padding: 2em, 0;
  flex: none;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* =================================================================
   Navigation
   ================================================================= */

nav ul {
  /* Turns off the bullets */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 1em;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  padding: .25em 0;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1AF1CE;
}

.active-page {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1AF1CE;
}

.active-page:hover {
  color: #1AF1CE;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container container-nav">
    <div class="logo-title">
      <img id="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="CubeWind Logo">
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" class="active-page">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="active-page">About Us</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="active-page">Our Services</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="active-page">Our Products</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="active-page">Contact Us</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- / .container -->
</header>
```

When I changed the display of `container-nav` into `display:flex;`, the navbar is taking 2 lines to display a single word. Here, I'm attaching a screenshot of the issue. Please help me to find the cause of this.

Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO8HC.png)

Comment: have you tried setting white-space: nowrap; on your <a> tags?
white-space: normal|nowrap|pre|pre-line|pre-wrap|initial|inherit;

Comment: I just tried it now. It fixed the issue. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It might fix the issue but it is not causing it, the reason it does it is because your logo is taking up a lot of space it doesnt need because of the `width: 20%;` if you can have a static width for you img that would be better eg: `width: 40px;`

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the suggestion. I really appreciate it.